# how to link 1st collection's item property with item from 2nd collection

Tags: vb.net, collections

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIq25.png)

```
Dim stations As New Collection
            Dim trains As New Collection
            For i = 1 To 60
                Dim new_station As New station
                With new_station
                    .id = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(0)
                    .name = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(1)
                    .t = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(4)
                    .name_t = new_station.name & new_station.t
                    .x = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(2)
                    .y = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(3)
                End With
                stations.Add(new_station, new_station.name_t)
            Next   
            Dim a, c, l, n As String
            Dim m, b As Single
            For i = 1 To 78 Step 2
                a = S_trainsDataSet.T.Rows(1)(i)
                b = S_trainsDataSet.T.Rows(1)(i + 1)
                c = a & b
                l = S_trainsDataSet.T.Rows(2)(i)
                m = S_trainsDataSet.T.Rows(2)(i + 1)
                n = l & m
                Dim new_train As New train
                With new_train
                    .id = S_trainsDataSet.T.Rows(0)(i)
                    .src_t = S_trainsDataSet.T.Rows(1)(i + 1)
                    .dst_t = S_trainsDataSet.T.Rows(2)(i + 1)
                    .src = stations.Item(c)
                    .dst = stations.Item(n)
                End With
                trains.Add(new_train, new_train.id.ToString())
            Next

            For Each station In stations
                station.come = New Collection
                station.go = New Collection
                For Each train In trains
                    If train.src.name_t = station.name_t Then
                        station.go.add(train, train.id.ToString())
                    End If
                    If train.dst.name_t = station.name_t Then
                        station.come.add(train, train.id.ToString())
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```

vb : property of item in the 1st item is item in the 2nd collection and vise versa .. when I delete an item .. it isn't updated as null in the other collection

how can we link items of the two collections with each other

Comment: How is this any different from your [**first question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535407/how-to-link-items-of-two-collections)? `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` still applies. Edit your first question instead of double-posting.

Comment: The `Collection` from the VB namespace is a very poor choice.  It isnt typed, so everything gets stored as `Object`.  I suspect that means `Option Strict` is not On as well.  Removing something from a collection wont get rid of it if something else has a reference to it.

Comment: @VisualVincent sorry for this ,, the first question was by another account which I can't get in now .. thanks for help, can you help me in detail I can't get the dictionary method for my problem well

Comment: @Plutonix what is another method to represent my data you suggest ?

Comment: There is no "dictionary method".  The `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` is a class.  Read about it, try to use it and if you then have specific issues with that, post a question about that specifically.

Comment: In your case you could probably use the Dictionary like this for your main collections: `Dictionary(Of station, New List(Of train))`. This will "link" a list of trains to the specified station. And as per Plutonix's comment, collections is a bad choice. As you use the collections' `Key` parameter you can just replace every collection with a `Dictionary(Of String, <class>)` - where _<class>_ is either for example your `train` or `station` class depending on what you need it for.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, ok I will try to do that thank you

Comment: @VisualVincent, what I get from your suggestion, that I will use three dictionaries .. one for stations, second for train, and the third one linking the stations for trains ... and when I iterate through the stations dictionary when I remove any item from it it will be null in the two other dictionaries ??

Comment: ![2Collections](http://www2.0zz0.com/2016/04/14/16/462859587.png).    ... what I want to do appear on that pic

Comment: No, the dictionaries won't be linked. But you would only need one main dictionary, where the stations are the keys and the trains are the values. Whenever you want to get the station linked to a train you'd just do: `<Your dictionary>.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Value.Contains(<train class>)).Key` - where the value is a `List(Of train)` and `<train class>` is the specific train you are getting the station from.

Comment: Alternatively, since classes are reference types you can make them implement `IDisposable` and when you remove something you also call `.Dispose()` on it. I don't know if it will set it to `Nothing`, but it won't be usable at least.

Comment: @VisualVincent, then I will iterate in the stations collection and remove the proposed one then removing the matching one in the dictionary with its trains and then removing these trains also from its collection and iterate again to remove the stations which trains have been just removed and so on ... is what I get right ??

Comment: No! You are not going to use any collections! Use only a `Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train))`! The code you have now is really messy, to keep it tidy you shouldn't reference any other class inside station/train. Use a single Dictionary and have separate train instances for each station.

Comment: Then modify your trains' properties to only have Booleans as for example `come = False` which would indicate wether the train comes or goes to/from the station. Then if you want to find all trains going from a specific station you would just have to iterate through the trains list for the station and check their properties. --- **Example:** `For Each t As train In <Your dictionary>(<station>)` and then check in an if-statement: `If train.come = False Then ...`.

Comment: @VisualVincent, I appreciate your help and your patience I got it thanks really for you

Comment: No problem. I'm going to write an answer with some examples...

Comment: @VisualVincent I will wait for it .. God bless you

Comment: It might take a little while though, as I'm currently sick. But you can expect it within 24 hours.

Comment: @VisualVincent, I hope you a quick recovery and I hope you won't forget me when you post that issue .. I need it really

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I haven't forgotten you, but I'm sorry I haven't written anything for a while. I am still working with the answer (I'm better now, by the way) but as I've been busy I have not had the time to finish it yet. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hello. I truly am sorry for not getting back to you with some code... As I've gotten well again I have really not had much spare time to be able to finish what's left of what I've already written (it's a little bit complex). I do apologize sincerely as I understand that you may have been waiting with hope. I know it's been almost two weeks, but I will try to finish the code as soon as possible. Thank you for your extreme patience.

Comment: @VisualVincent don't worry you are an angle .. I try to manage my things .. deeply thanks for remember me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a very long wait I finally got some time over to finish this. Very sorry for the extremely long wait.

I don't know if it's fully what you're looking for, but it will make the `train` and `station` classes work more together.

---

As you have so many collections (as they're even within your classes) it's hard to update them all. I'd recommend you to use a `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` and just having Boolean properties in your `train` classes. Your Dictionary would look like this: `Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train))`.

First we'll need some extensions methods to later help us find and iterate through the stations and trains. We'll start with a function that will find a station by specifying it's name.

Create a new `Module` and add this code within:

```
''' <summary>
''' Finds a station by it's name.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="StationCollection">The dictionary to look for the station in.</param>
''' <param name="Name">The name of the station to find.</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function FindStationByName(ByRef StationCollection As Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train)), ByVal Name As String) As station
    Name = Name.ToLower() 'ToLower() provides case-insensitive checking.

    'Iterating through a Dictionary requires iterating through it's keys, as it's not index based.
    For Each k As station In StationCollection.Keys
        If k.name_t.ToLower() = Name Then
            Return k
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Then we need extension methods for finding a train by it's id or it's name. We also an extension for finding all trains linked to a specific station. In the same module as above add:

```
''' <summary>
''' Finds a train by it's ID.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="TrainCollection">The list to look for the train in.</param>
''' <param name="Id">The ID of the train to find.</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function FindTrainById(ByRef TrainCollection As List(Of train), ByVal Id As Integer) As train
    For Each t As train In TrainCollection
        If t.id = Id Then
            Return t
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Finds a train by it's name.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="TrainCollection">The list to look for the train in.</param>
''' <param name="TrainName">The name of the train to find.</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function FindTrainByName(ByRef TrainCollection As List(Of train), ByVal TrainName As String) As train
    TrainName = TrainName.ToLower()

    For Each t As train In TrainCollection
        If t.name_t = TrainName Then
            Return t
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Finds all trains linked to the specified station.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="StationCollection">The dictionary to look for the station in.</param>
''' <param name="StationName">The name of the station which's trains to find.</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function FindTrainsByStation(ByRef StationCollection As Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train)), ByVal StationName As String) As List(Of train)
    StationName = StationName.ToLower()

    For Each k As station In StationCollection.Keys
        If k.name_t.ToLower() = StationName Then
            Return StationCollection(k)
        End If
    Next

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Finally we'll need an extension method to remove a train from all the stations. This extension method will be used by the `RemoveAll()` and `RemoveAllByName()` methods in the `train` class later.

```
''' <summary>
''' Removes a trains link from all stations.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="StationCollection">The dictionary of stations which's links to this train to remove.</param>
''' <param name="train">The train to remove.</param>
''' <param name="MatchName">If true, match by the train's name instead of it's ID.</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Sub RemoveTrainFromAllStations(ByVal StationCollection As Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train)), ByVal train As train, ByVal MatchName As Boolean)
    For Each k As station In StationCollection.Keys

        For i = 0 To StationCollection(k).Count - 1
            Dim t As train = StationCollection(k)(i)

            If MatchName = False Then 'Wether to match against the train's name or id.
                If t.id = train.id Then
                    t.Remove()
                End If

            Else
                If t.name_t = train.name_t Then
                    t.Remove()
                End If

            End If
        Next

    Next
End Sub
```

---

Now onto your classes.

Passing the Dictionary reference to your `station` and `train` classes can also help you create functions for checking which train belongs to which station, etc. By doing this you have the classes working together with the Dictionary, you can even make another wrapper class around this to reduce "messieness" even more.

You will also need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in order for dictionaries and hash tables to be able to lookup your key correctly.

This is just example code, so I haven't included your properties here:

```
Public Class train
    Private StationCollection As Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train)) 'Storing the main dictionary.
    Private _parent As station

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Wether this train is departing or arriving.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property Departing As Boolean = False

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The station that owns this train (multiple stations can own trains with the same names and IDs).
    ''' This is mainly used for internal functions.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public ReadOnly Property ParentStation As station
        Get
            Return _parent
        End Get
    End Property



    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the train class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="StationCollection">The main dictionary containing this train and it's station.</param>
    ''' <param name="ParentStation">The station that owns this train (multiple stations can own trains with the same names and IDs).</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New(ByRef StationCollection As Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train)), ByVal ParentStation As station)
        Me.StationCollection = StationCollection
        Me._parent = ParentStation
    End Sub



    ''' <summary>
    ''' Removes this train from it's station.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub Remove()
        Me.StationCollection(ParentStation).Remove(Me)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Removes this, and all other trains having the same ID as this, from all stations in the main dictionary.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub RemoveAll()
        Me.StationCollection.RemoveTrainFromAllStations(Me, False)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Removes this, and all other trains having the same name as this, from all stations in the main dictionary.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub RemoveAllByName()
        Me.StationCollection.RemoveTrainFromAllStations(Me, True)
    End Sub


    'the rest of your code...


    'Overriding Equals() and GetHashCode(), comparison will be performed by comparing two trains' id's.
    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return obj IsNot Nothing AndAlso obj.GetType() Is GetType(train) AndAlso DirectCast(obj, train).id = Me.id
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return Me.id.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

And the `station` class:

```
Public Class station
    Private StationCollection As Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train)) 'Linking this station to the main Dictionary.

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a list of trains arriving at this station. Modifying the returned list will NOT affect the main dictionary or it's stations.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public ReadOnly Property ArrivingTrains As List(Of train)
        Get
            Return Me.GetTrainsByType(False)
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets a list of trains departing from this station. Modifying the returned list will NOT affect the main dictionary or it's stations.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public ReadOnly Property DepartingTrains As List(Of train)
        Get
            Return Me.GetTrainsByType(True)
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets all trains of the specified type that are linked to this station.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Departing">Wether to get all departing trains or all arriving trains.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function GetTrainsByType(ByVal Departing As Boolean) As List(Of train)
        Dim TrainList As List(Of train) = StationCollection(Me) 'Getting all trains for this station.
        Dim ReturnList As New List(Of train)

        For Each t As train In TrainList
            If t.Departing = Departing Then
                ReturnList.Add(t)
            End If
        Next

        Return ReturnList
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Removes this station and all links to trains arriving or departing from it.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub Remove()
        For Each t As train In StationCollection(Me) 'Iterate though all the trains for this station.
            GetType(train).GetField("_parent", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(t, Nothing) 'Use reflection to set the train's parent to Nothing.
        Next

        StationCollection.Remove(Me)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the station class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="StationCollection">The main dictionary containing this train and it's station.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New(ByRef StationCollection As Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train)))
        Me.StationCollection = StationCollection
    End Sub

    'the rest of your code...

    'Overriding Equals() and GetHashCode(), comparison will be performed by comparing two stations' names.
    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return obj IsNot Nothing AndAlso obj.GetType() Is GetType(station) AndAlso DirectCast(obj, station).name_t = Me.name_t
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return Me.name_t.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

---

### Adding new stations/trains

When adding items to the dictionary you would first have to initialize a new `station` class, then you create new `train` classes where you point the `ParentStation` parameter to the station you just created.

For example:

```
Dim MainDictionary As New Dictionary(Of station, List(Of train)) 'Create the dictionary (only do this once, unless you need multiple of course).

Dim new_station As New station(MainDictionary) 'Create a new station.
new_station.name = "Station 1"

MainDictionary.Add(new_station, New List(Of train))

Dim new_train As New train(MainDictionary, new_station) 'Create a new train.
new_train.id = 3
new_train.name_t = "Train 1"
new_train.Departing = True 'This train is leaving from the station.

MainDictionary(new_station).Add(new_train) 'Add the train to the station.
```

---

### Extension methods

The extension methods are used when...

- **You want to find a specific station by it's name.**

  For example:

  ```
  Dim st As station = MainDictionary.FindStationByName("Station 1")
  ```
- **You want to find a train by it's id or name.**

  For example:

  ```
  Dim t As train = MainDictionary.FindStationByName("Station 1").ArrivingTrains.FindTrainById(3)
  Dim t2 As train = MainDictionary.FindStationByName("Station 1").ArrivingTrains.FindTrainByName("Train 1")
  ```
- **Or when you want to get all trains from a specific station (by it's name).**

  For example:

  ```
  Dim trains As List(Of train) = MainDictionary.FindTrainsByStation("Station 1")
  ```

---

### Overview of the methods, fields and properties:

### - The `train` class -

**StationCollection**

- A private field holding the reference to your main dictionary of all stations.

**_parent**

- A private field holding the station this train is "linked" to.

**Departing**

- A public property indicating if this train is departing (leaving) or arriving (coming)

**ParentStation**

- A public read-only property returning the value of `_parent`.

**Remove()**

- Removes this train from the station it's linked to.

**RemoveAll()**

- Removes this train, and all other trains having the same ID as this, from all stations in the main dictionary.

**RemoveAllByName()**

- Same as `RemoveAll()`, but matches against the trains' names instead of their IDs.

---

### - The `station` class -

**StationCollection**

- Same as in the `train` class.

**ArrivingTrains**

- A read-only property returning all trains arriving at (coming to) this station.

**DepartingTrains**

- A read-only property returning all trains departing (leaving) from this station.

**GetTrainsByType()**

- A private method for getting arriving/departing trains. Used by the above properties.

**Remove()**

- Removes this station and all links to arriving or departing trains (by nullifying their `_parent` field) that are in the main dictionary.

---

Hope this helps! And sorry again for taking so long.

Comment: you needn't to be sorry I appreciate your help too much, no words can express my deep thanks to you .. I still have an issue 
I have about 400,000 nodes that means it will be 400,000 item in the dictionary can I use a dictionary (of train, list of station) it will be less size and I want to use pointer for every station just when I change a property of any station through the dictionary it changes too in the same station anywhere ... can it be ??

Comment: @AlKobtan : Yes, but then you would have to keep track of the stations. Because if you create a new station all the time it won't work, you must add the **exact** same station class everywhere you want it then. If you reverse the logic of my code to fit `Dictionary(Of train, List(Of station))` you could find a station by it's name, and add it to new trains whenever you like. Keep in mind that swapping the classes will require you to rewrite the extension methods so that the train specific ones are used for the stations. For example you will use `FindByTrainByName`'s logic to find a station.

Comment: how this can be done ?? you could find a station by it's name, and add it to new trains whenever you like by not creating it as new one ??

Comment: @AlKobtan : So for the above mentioned dictionary you just have to change all previous `train` to `station`, and all previous `station` to `train` in all the required methods.

Comment: @AlKobtan : Modify the `FindTrainByName` method so that it looks for `station` instead. Then you just get the station it returns when you call it and add it to a new place in the dictionary.

Comment: Ok I will give it a shot now, Bod Bless you you are a wonderful man

Comment: It was wonderful dear my friend .. I implement your module in my method and the result was 25 ms compared to 200 ms 
I created on list for all stations .. and then a dictionary (of train, list of station) items of list are extracted from the list by `FindStationbyName` and the result was magnificent